# bash find using variable

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, find

I have an issue I don't understand. It is simple and it should work, but it doesn't.
=EDITED exactly what I can see from terminal=
I have a list of filenames:

```
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ cat LIST
IMG_9282.JPG
IMG_9287.JPG
IMG_9300.JPG
IMG_9324.JPG
IMG_9329.JPG
IMG_9463.JPG
IMG_9412.JPG
IMG_9562.JPG
IMG_9511.JPG
IMG_9607.JPG
```

and want to search for every file in list it's path via find command:

```
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ for i in `cat LIST`; do find /mnt/c/e-m10/  -name "$i";  done
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$
```

no results, when I exchange it for echo $i (to check if variable $i is OK, it works)

```
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ for i in `cat LIST`;do echo "$i" ;  done
IMG_9282.JPG
IMG_9287.JPG
IMG_9300.JPG
IMG_9324.JPG
IMG_9329.JPG
IMG_9463.JPG
IMG_9412.JPG
IMG_9562.JPG
IMG_9511.JPG
IMG_9607.JPG
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$
```

when I do it manually, set variable (without loop) it works:

```
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ i=IMG_9607.JPG
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name "$i"        
/mnt/c/e-m10/IMG_9607.JPG
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should work. can you report output of `file LIST`

Comment: $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.24(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: You seem not have copied the actual output, based on the variation in spaces before `for` and the `$` in your result of `find`. Please update the question with copy and paste the complete sequence as appears in your terminal.

Comment: It would also be more of a check if you checked with `for i in `cat LIST`;do echo "$i" ABC;  done` as `cat LIST` would give the output you indicate as well. You could also have done `for i in `cat LIST`; do echo find /mnt/c/e-m10/  -name "$i";  done` and try one of the commands with copy and paste.

Comment: yes output of file LIST is so long, it is truncated, so I just copy pasted them

Comment: @moini, in that case you should always make your test smaller by truncating LIST and copy the real thing.

Comment: @Anthon , I just did it. edited my post, you can see real outputs now.

Comment: This work for me, getting series of commands (usable but I still dont understand this behaviour) `[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ for i in `cat LIST`; do echo find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name "$i"; done
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9282.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9287.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9300.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9324.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9329.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9463.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9412.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9562.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9511.JPG
find /mnt/c/e-m10/ -name IMG_9607.JPG`

Comment: @moini your very last output (`$ /mnt/c/e-m10/100OLYMP/P6220454.JPG`) still doesn't look real (because of the `$`). And make sure you have `P6220454.JPG` in your `LIST` file, update the info in an edit of the question, comments mangle most formatted output

Comment: @Anthon: I fixed it in my post.

Comment: If there's a chance the LIST contains special characters, you can clean it changing your `cat` in something like `cat LIST | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9._\n'`. This will clean the file list removing all characters but the ones listed there

Comment: @SPIDER: helped to remove special character form LIST file, but did not helped to work with find. `[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ cat -v LIST | tail -1 && cat -v LIST2 | tail -1
IMG_9607.JPG^M
IMG_9607.JPG
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a `cat -v LIST` to see if there are any special characters that you don't see with a simple echo. I suspect DOS line endings, i.e. extraneous carriage returns before the newline.

EDIT: to convert the LIST file:

```
dos2unix < LIST > LIST.new && mv LIST.new LIST
```

Or if you don't have dos2unix, but do have vim: `vim LIST`, then `:set notx`, then `:wq`

Comment: `[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ cat -v LIST
IMG_9282.JPG^M
IMG_9287.JPG^M
IMG_9300.JPG^M
IMG_9324.JPG^M
IMG_9329.JPG^M
IMG_9463.JPG^M
IMG_9412.JPG^M
IMG_9562.JPG^M
IMG_9511.JPG^M
IMG_9607.JPG^M
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$`

Comment: As I suspected (see the ^M attached to each name).

Comment: @Hello Wurtel: this hint helped me a LOT, I set out those ^M endings via vim editor and it works now! :) But I have question - how it comes, that when I use only linux I have such endings in the LIST file? I use xfce4-terminal

Comment: You don't show / tell how you created the LIST file so I can't answer your question.

Comment: This answer helped me. In my case I had piped output from a grep that had colorized output. The filenames appear to have terminal color reset characters on the end: `local-lambda-bucket.yml^[[m^[[K`

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cd /tmp/test
$ cat > LIST << EOD
> IMG_9324.JPG
> IMG_9329.JPG
> IMG_9463.JPG
> IMG_9412.JPG
> IMG_9562.JPG
> IMG_9511.JPG
> IMG_9607.JPG
> EOD
$ mkdir e
$ touch e/IMG_9607.JPG
$ touch e/IMG_9412.JPG
$ find .
.
./e
./e/IMG_9412.JPG
./e/IMG_9607.JPG
./LIST
$ for i in `cat LIST`; do find e/  -name "$i";  done
e/IMG_9412.JPG
e/IMG_9607.JPG
$
```

Therefore start from the above, then replace LIST with the real and then `e/`. If you are not reaching an internal Bash limit for the for loop (which should throw an error) you must be doing something else wrong which is not in your example output.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud you provide a sample file listing in the folder /mnt/c/e-m10/ ?

In the meantime, could you try the below command ?

```
for i in `cat LIST`; do echo $i; find /mnt/c/e-m10/  -iname $i -print;  done
```

This will print any info as needed also, it ignores case sensitivity as well.

Comment: it works only for "echo" part `[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ for i in `cat LIST`; do echo $i; find /mnt/c/e-m10/  -iname $i -print;  done
IMG_9282.JPG
IMG_9287.JPG
IMG_9300.JPG
IMG_9324.JPG
IMG_9329.JPG
IMG_9463.JPG
IMG_9412.JPG
IMG_9562.JPG
IMG_9511.JPG
IMG_9607.JPG
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$`

Comment: listing in the related folder : `[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ ls -la /mnt/c/e-m10/       
total 1784
drwxrwxrwx 1 molni users      0 Sep 19 09:53 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 molni users  24576 Sep  3 21:52 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 molni users 262144 Aug 17 23:58 100OLYMP
drwxrwxrwx 1 molni users 393216 Sep 12 13:41 101OLYMP
drwxrwxrwx 1 molni users 393216 Aug 29 23:19 102OLYMP
drwxrwxrwx 1 molni users 393216 Aug 12 19:16 103OLYMP
drwxrwxrwx 1 molni users 344064 Sep 12 13:39 104OLYMP
drwxrwxrwx 1 molni users  16384 Aug 31 23:08 upravene
[molni@archlinux picasa_album]$ `